# Permission systems

Tags: django, permissions

I have objects in my system with relations to owners and collaborators and now I need to add permissions on viewing these objects. Currently if the user is the owner or listed as a collaborator they can see the object. I have that logic encapsulated already but it seems the "proper" way would be to use a row level permission system and assign these users permissions. However that becomes more complicated when it comes to assigning and removing permissions and also makes viewing more expensive as it has to look up permissions in the database rather then relying on data that is already being accessed. I have been looking into django-guardian and it seems like overkill right now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [django-logical-rules](https://bitbucket.org/aashe/django-logical-rules). Rules are written in python and you can pass existing objects to a rule, so their isn't necessarily a db hit... although I would recommend caching. Rules can be easily integrated with generic views and accessible with a template tag.